# Unable to insert into DB from Mule Groovy

Tags: groovy, mule, mule-studio

I have a Database table **GroovyTest** as following :-

[image]

As you can see it has 4 fields :- **ID**, **NAME**,**AGE** and **DESIGNATION** and among them **ID** and **AGE** are integer type and remaining **NAME** and **DESIGNATION** are String

Now I have the following Mule flow which is trying to insert the values in this DB using Groovy Script:-

```
<flow name="GroovyWithJDBCFlow1" doc:name="GroovyWithJDBCFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" path="groovy" doc:name="HTTP"/>
  <scripting:component doc:name="Initialise Database"> 
            <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
                <scripting:text><![CDATA[
               jdbcConnector = muleContext.getRegistry().lookupConnector("Database_Global");
                qr = jdbcConnector.getQueryRunner();
                conn = jdbcConnector.getConnection();
                qr.update(conn, "INSERT INTO GroovyTest VALUES(message.getInboundProperty('id'),message.getInboundProperty('name'),message.getInboundProperty('age'),message.getInboundProperty('designation'))")
return "Inserted into Table";]]></scripting:text>
       </scripting:script>  
        </scripting:component>
</flow>
```

Now when I trigger the flow with following url :- `http://localhost:8082/groovy/?method=insert&id=1&name=Anirban&age=29&designation=SoftwareEngineer`

I am getting following exception :-

```
Root Exception stack trace:
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot find either column "message" or the user-defined function or aggregate "message.getInboundProperty", or the name is ambiguous.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:196)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1454)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:388)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

But if I hardcode the value as following :-`qr.update(conn, "INSERT INTO GroovyTest VALUES(5,'testvalue',333,'test')");` it's getting inserted without any issue ..

Also I checked the log .. I am getting all the inbound properties value correctly but I am unable to make it insert in DB using Groovy

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are literally passing `message.getInboundProperty('id')` (and so on) to the database, in the SQL string, which of course can not work.

You need to pass the value, like this:

```
"INSERT INTO GroovyTest VALUES(${message.getInboundProperty('id')}, ...
```

But stop right here: this is **a very bad idea** as it is open to SQL injection, since you're exposing this over HTTP.

Instead do:

```
qr.update(conn,
          'INSERT INTO GroovyTest VALUES (?,?,?,?)',
          message.getInboundProperty('id').toInteger(),
          message.getInboundProperty('name'),
          message.getInboundProperty('age').toInteger(),
          message.getInboundProperty('designation'))
```

Comment: It's also generally a bad idea to directly interact with the Database connector in a groovy script.  Try doing this with the [DB connector](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Database+Connector). You'll be able to use MEL in your query, and the DB connector will automatically use a parameterized PreparedStatement to run it.

Comment: I've seen other posts from the OP where he uses the DB connector so I assumed he's aware of this connector and wants to explore alternative approaches. As you said, bypassing a transport when there's one available is usually a bad idea, as you lose the extra features provided by Mule (error handling, stats, etc...).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to David and the final working solution is :-

```
 <scripting:component doc:name="Initialise Database"> 
            <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
                        <scripting:text><![CDATA[
               import org.mule.api.transport.*;// For PropertyScope.INBOUND
               import org.apache.commons.dbutils.handlers.ArrayHandler;
                jdbcConnector = muleContext.getRegistry().lookupConnector("Database_Global");
                qr = jdbcConnector.getQueryRunner();
                conn = jdbcConnector.getConnection();
                log.info('NAME ' + message.getProperty('name',PropertyScope.INBOUND)) ;

                qr.update(conn,'INSERT INTO getData (ID,NAME,AGE,DESIGNATION) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',(Integer) message.getInboundProperty('id').toInteger(), message.getInboundProperty('name'), (Integer) message.getInboundProperty('age').toInteger(),message.getInboundProperty('designation'));
  log.info('Data inserted Successfully');            
return "Data inserted Successfully";]]></scripting:text>

       </scripting:script>  
        </scripting:component>
```

And yes I agree with David and Ryan that this is not a useful approach to use Groovy to interact with DB .. but yes, this is an alternate approach